# How to move selection in photoshop without leaving the black background behind?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background

I'm new to Photoshop. I want to move a selection but when I move it just leave a black background behind. Then I have to brush that black background after that. Is there anyway to move a selection and leave a proper background behind?
Here is the photo. I just want to move the "logi" word a bit to the right (for centralizing) but it just leave a ugly black background behind (instead of grey like the photo's background)
[image: blackbackground]

Comment: The key is to detach "logi" into its own layer and then patch up the void by basically painting over it with clone stamp tool, just like I assume you did with the text "tech", that I can by the way still see a little bit of. Content aware fill as the first step might speed it up a bit. But to kinda answer the question in the title... you can't. Whenever you're moving stuff in a photo like this, it's basically the same as cutting a part of a printed photo with scissors and then wondering why there's now a hole in the photo.  The only thing you can do is fill it afterwards or leave it as is.

Answer (score 1):

The "grey" is **not** the "photos background". The grey **is** the photo. You can't cut and move a portion of a photo and expect things to magically repair where you've cut something. You need to do that manually.

- Select and copy the portion of the logo you wish to remain so it is on its own, new, layer.
- Just as you've covered up the right side of the logo, cover up the *entire* logo.
- You can then position your logo on its own layer wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select, and copy and paste the logo to a new layer
2. Select the original layer in the layers panel
3. Select a rectangle around the original logo and do *Edit > Fill*, and choose the content aware option. This will erase the logo from that layer and fill the gap based on the surrounding content.
4. Move your logo into position

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the lasso tool (or the Object Selection tool) and draw around the type

[image]

Now choose the Content Aware Move tool and move the type where you want it placed

[image]

All elements of the logo need to be on the same layer to do this...

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the easiest way. I tried to work with the layer thing but it's quite hard. But with this Content Aware Move tool it's much easier.

Comment: You're very welcome - glad to help you with this. :)